# modify binary output before returning to the prompt mode

Tags: pipe, io-redirection

I have a binary which prints the question and then waits for a user answer. I have no access to the source code of this binary, but I want to modify the screen output.

Example:

```
> ./commandx 
 Day 1
 Day 2
 Day 3
 Please type the number:
```

I want to dipslay:

```
Night 1
Night 2
Night 3
Please type the number:
```

The pipe solution isn't working in this case.

Example:

```
./commandx | sed 's/Day/Night/g'

 Day 1
 Day 2
 Day 3
 Please type the number:
```

then it waits for user choice, but `Day` hasn't changed into `Night`

Comment: Check which file descriptor `./commandx` uses to write the output. It might be something else than fd `1`/`stdout`. You could use `strace` to see what your program does on the system-call level.

Comment: I've checked with strace: it write to the STDERR 
write(2, "Day 1", ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the binary with strace and found that it write to the STDERR write(2, "Day 1", ...)
So I redirected the output from STDERR to STDOUT and modified it on the fly

```
commandx 2>&1 | perl -pe 's/Day/Night/g
```